# paypal UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY

Tags: paypal

I am getting an UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY but the error is to generic to figure out what to do. This exact code works perfectly in a sandbox. But it makes sense business validation might fail on live. Any insight into how to debug what the issue is?

```
(
    [name] => UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
    [message] => The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.
    [debug_id] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [field] => invoiceId
                    [value] => INV2-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
                    [location] => path
                    [issue] => REQUEST_REJECTED
                    [description] => Could not process the request. Please contact customer service team for any queries.
                )

        )

    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors
                    [method] => GET
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You're going to have to supply more information about what you are doing, including the full request and response.

Answer (score 0):

After days of working with Paypal support. It turns out that this is due to it being a new account. They implemented some "system" that builds a reputation before you can use invoices at all and there is no clear path on how to "establish". So you should avoid paypal for any new accounts entirely.

Comment: So new accounts could not use paypal invoice api? I also facing same issue

Comment: correct. If you call them and talk to them this is what they will tell you